# Access dropbox api without clientside authentication?

Tags: api, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I'm trying to create a smooth solution for sharing files with a custom presentation of the files (logos fonts etc).

My ideal would be to put the files in a dropbox folder and then have a webpage, on a separate server, access those files over javascript and display a list of them linked to the actual files.

A demand is that the end user don't have to authenticate with a dropbox acocunt in order to access the files. I would rather like to use a public folder or use files from another account.

Is there any way to maintain a auth-session serverside, something like a permanent sessionID or something like that?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, however, you could use CURL to reauthenticate with each request. Review: [Wordpress Dev Network](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/)

Comment: How is that done, isn't the authentification done in a form on dropbox.com?

Comment: You will probably need to get an authorization code for your app, and hard code it, since youare okay with using the same drop box account, or public folder...so that account will need to approve you app, then simply hard code that into your PHP Script. Just skip over the parts asking for a authkey and hard code it to a variable.

Comment: Just do the authentication one time, approve your app, get your authentication key, and in the code: `$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();
print_r($accountInfo);` change: "$accessToken" to your authentication key, or put the line: `"$accessToken = "{authentication code here}";` above that code...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do the authentication one time, approve your app, get your authentication key, and in the code:

```
$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();
print_r($accountInfo);
```

Change:

```
$accessToken to "{Your auth key}"
```

or put the line:

```
$accessToken = "{authentication code here}";
```

above that code.