# How to show all files and folder from dropbox?

Tags: php, dropbox

There are different files and folder in my dropbox account. I have a website and what i have to do is list all files and folder in that website from dropbox account . User who visits my website sees it automatically with out logging in or doing any kind of authentication..Is this possible simply to make api call and showing data?

Comment: Yes, you can do that just make an api call and render a list of files in read-only mode. what have you tried ?

Comment: I am confused just how to start it.Can you provide me any refrence link?

Comment: Lookup Dropbox sdk for php

Comment: Have you checked `Dropbox Dev Center` ? IANGIFY though :)

Comment: i have checked through documentation and it says i have to make an app and request files through access token. I think access token can be obtained only through authenticating isn't it?

Comment: go through this link this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636124/access-dropbox-api-without-clientside-authentication